# Is extjs's buffered scrolling suitable for images?

Tags: extjs

I am looking around for an extjs solution to load very many records.I have over 3000 records in mind.In the example This example illustrates loading of all the records up front and buffering the rendering.

In the demonstration http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/buffer-grid.html its written

> This example illustrates loading of all the records up front and
>   buffering the rendering

Is this method of loading all the records suitable for images?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ExtJS's buffered scrolling is suitable for images.

Add a renderer to your column that generates this html as the column content:

```
<img src=".....">
```

Your browser will do the rest requesting all images. [This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/744363/1385429) tells you how to add the image column.